# video streaming from android to media player in C#

Tags: c#, android, video-streaming

i want to make a simple video streaming. the application i used is android and simple media player using c#. most of the code i review will have POST method to the ip server. meanwhile my application is using gsm network which it will require to use data packet in transferring data media.

my first step is having an android application which can be record. this step is done. this is my code.

```
public class Videotest1Activity extends Activity implements 
    SurfaceHolder.Callback, OnInfoListener, OnErrorListener{

    Camera camera;
VideoView videoView;
SurfaceHolder holder;
TextView msg;
Button initBtn, startBtn, stopBtn, playBtn, stprevBtn;
MediaRecorder recorder;

String outputFileName;
static final String TAG = "RecordVideo";
int maxDuration = 7000;//7sec
int frameRate = 1;//15

String serverIP = "172.19.117.12";
int serverPort = 2000;
Socket socket;

int mCount;
//TimerThread mTimer;

Chronometer chronometer;

LocalSocket receiver,sender;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_videotest1);

    videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
    initBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.initialize);
    startBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    stopBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    msg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    playBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reviewBtn);
    stprevBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stprevBtn);
    chronometer = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer1);

    /*
    mTimer= new TimerThread();
    mTimer.setOnAlarmListener(mSTimer_OnAlarm);
    mTimer.setPeriod(100);
    */
}

public void buttonTapped(View view){
    switch(view.getId()){
    case R.id.initialize:
        initRecorder();
        break;
    case R.id.button1:
        beginRecording();
        break;
    case R.id.button3:
        stopRecording();
        break;
    case R.id.reviewBtn:
        playRecording();
        break;
    case R.id.stprevBtn:
        stopPlayback();
        break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onError(MediaRecorder mr, int what, int extra) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Record error");
    stopRecording();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Recording limit reached", 2500).show();
}

@Override
public void onInfo(MediaRecorder mr, int what, int extra) {
    Log.i(TAG, "recording event");
    if(what == MediaRecorder.MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_DURATION_REACHED){
        Log.i(TAG, "...max duration reached");
        stopRecording();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Recording limit info", 2500).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {

}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
    Log.v(TAG, "in surfaceCreated");

    try{
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        camera.startPreview();
    }catch(IOException e){
        Log.v(TAG, "Could not start the preview");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    initBtn.setEnabled(true);
    startBtn.setEnabled(true);
    stopBtn.setEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {

}

protected void onResume(){
    Log.v(TAG, "in onResume");
    super.onResume();
    initBtn.setEnabled(false);
    startBtn.setEnabled(false);
    stopBtn.setEnabled(false);
    playBtn.setEnabled(false);
    stprevBtn.setEnabled(false);
    if(!initCamera())
        finish();
}

public boolean initCamera(){
    try{
        camera = Camera.open();
        Camera.Parameters camParam = camera.getParameters();
        camera.lock();
        holder = videoView.getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(this);
        holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        //Thread thread = new Thread(new hantarThread());
        //thread.start();
    }catch(RuntimeException re){
        Log.v(TAG, "Could not initialize the camera");
        re.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public void initRecorder(){
    if(recorder != null)return;     
    outputFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/videooutput.mp4";

    File outputFile = new File(outputFileName);
    if(outputFile.exists())
        outputFile.delete();//knp nk dlt?

    try{
        Toast.makeText(this, "InitRecord", 2500).show();
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.unlock();
        recorder = new MediaRecorder();
        recorder.setCamera(camera);

        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
        recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        recorder.setVideoSize(176, 144);
        recorder.setVideoFrameRate(15);//15
        recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);//mpeg_4
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        recorder.setMaxDuration(60000);
        recorder.setPreviewDisplay(holder.getSurface());
        recorder.setOutputFile(outputFileName);

        recorder.prepare();
        Log.v(TAG, "MediaRecorder initialized");
        initBtn.setEnabled(false);
        startBtn.setEnabled(true);
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.v(TAG, "MediaRecorder failed");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void beginRecording(){
    //mCount = 0;
    //mTimer.start();

    try{
        Log.v(TAG, "start Recording begin");

        int stoppedMilliseconds = 0;
          String chronoText = chronometer.getText().toString();
          String array[] = chronoText.split(":");
          if (array.length == 2) {
            stoppedMilliseconds = Integer.parseInt(array[0]) * 60 * 1000
                + Integer.parseInt(array[1]) * 1000;
          } else if (array.length == 3) {
            stoppedMilliseconds = Integer.parseInt(array[0]) * 60 * 60 * 1000 
                + Integer.parseInt(array[1]) * 60 * 1000
                + Integer.parseInt(array[2]) * 1000;
          }
          chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - stoppedMilliseconds);

        //chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());           
        chronometer.start();
        Log.v(TAG, "timer start");
        long dTime = chronometer.getDrawingTime();
        long autoLink = chronometer.getAutoLinkMask();          

        Log.v(TAG, "getDrawingTime: " + dTime);
        Log.v(TAG, "AutoLink: " + autoLink);

        recorder.setOnInfoListener(this);
        recorder.setOnErrorListener(this);
        recorder.start();               

        msg.setText("Recording");
        startBtn.setEnabled(false);
        stopBtn.setEnabled(true);
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.v(TAG, "start Recording failed");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}

public void stopRecording(){
    if(recorder != null){
        recorder.setOnErrorListener(null);
        recorder.setOnInfoListener(null);
        try{
            recorder.stop();
            Log.v(TAG, "stop Record Begin");

            chronometer.stop();
            Log.v(TAG, "Timer stop");
            //mTimer.stop();
        }catch(IllegalStateException e){
            Log.e(TAG, "stop is ILLEGAL");
        }
        releaseRecorder();
        msg.setText("");
        releaseCamera();
        startBtn.setEnabled(false);
        stopBtn.setEnabled(false);
        playBtn.setEnabled(true);
    }
    else{
        Log.v(TAG, "video cannot stop. Video null");
        long autoLink = chronometer.getAutoLinkMask();
        Log.v(TAG, "stop aLink: " + autoLink);                              
        long elapsedMillis = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - chronometer.getBase();
        Log.v(TAG, "elapsedMillis: " + elapsedMillis);
    }
}

private void releaseCamera(){
    if(camera != null){
        try{
            camera.reconnect();
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
    }
}

private void releaseRecorder(){
    if(recorder != null){
        recorder.release();
        recorder = null;
    }
}

private void playRecording(){
    MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
    videoView.setMediaController(mc);
    videoView.setVideoPath(outputFileName);
    videoView.start();
    stprevBtn.setEnabled(true);
}

private void stopPlayback(){
    videoView.stopPlayback();
}       

}
```

}

next step i make is makes the media player can be play videooutput.mp4. in here, to make it play, it first must load the video then played. well, this is for the second step. it works well too. here's my code.

```
private void button6_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            // create video source
            FileVideoSource fileSource = new FileVideoSource(openFileDialog1.FileName);

            // open it
            OpenVideoSource(fileSource);
        }
    }

    // Open video source
    private void OpenVideoSource(IVideoSource source)
    {
        // set busy cursor
        this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        // stop current video source
        CloseCurrentVideoSource();
        // start new video source
        videoSourcePlayer.VideoSource = source;
        videoSourcePlayer.Start();                        
        // reset stop watch
        stopWatch = null;
        // start timer
        videoTimer.Start();

        this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
    }

    // New frame received by the player
    private void videoSourcePlayer_NewFrame(object sender, ref Bitmap image)
    {
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(image);

        // paint current time
        SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
        g.DrawString(now.ToString(), this.Font, brush, new PointF(5, 5));
        brush.Dispose();

        g.Dispose();
    }

    // Close video source if it is running
    private void CloseCurrentVideoSource()
    {
        if (videoSourcePlayer.VideoSource != null)
        {
            videoSourcePlayer.SignalToStop();
            // wait ~ 3 seconds
            for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
            {
                if (!videoSourcePlayer.IsRunning)
                    break;
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
            if (videoSourcePlayer.IsRunning)
            {
                videoSourcePlayer.Stop();
            }
            videoSourcePlayer.VideoSource = null;
        }
    }
```

im using AForge for the media player in c#. All i did is adding the reference of AForge.Controls, AForge.Video and AForge.Video.DirectShow.

now, what i need to do is sending the media data to the media player(c#) byte by byte. i dont have a clue how to make this happen. i also found sample coding [IP camera android](http://code.google.com/p/ipcamera-for-android/source/browse/) which it bring the video to the server. however, i still dont have a clue to do it in my apps.

note that the gsm will require number phone of the simcard used and also port number of the modem gsm.

can anybody help me with this. or perhaps giving me some idea on modifying the code. any helps is appreciated. thanks for advance.